# Why Braintree Payment Plugin not Working?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, paypal, braintree

I am trying to integrate `Braintree Plugin` but I am getting error. Can anyone help me?

I have to enable PayPal that's the reason I am using Braintree plugin. But I am confused about how to integrate this plugin with the server. There is nothing mention in the plugin.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:braintree_payment/braintree_payment.dart';

 void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Barintree Payment',
  theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.teal),
  home: Payment(),
);
}
}

class Payment extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_PaymentState createState() => _PaymentState();
}

class _PaymentState extends State<Payment> {
String clientNonce="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";

proceedPayNow() async {
BraintreePayment braintreePayment = new BraintreePayment();
var data = await braintreePayment.showDropIn(
    nonce: clientNonce, amount: "5.0", enableGooglePay: true);
print("Payment responce $data");
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Pay"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: payNow,
      color: Colors.teal,
      child: Text(
        "Proceed to Payment",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Error

```
Response of the payment {message: BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity missing, 
incorrectly configured in AndroidManifest.xml or another app defines the same
browser switch url as this app.
```

Can anyone help me please how Can I integrate it or any other way to integrate Paypal?

Comment: Did you add  `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true"/>` inside AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Comment: Yes I already added.

Comment: But tell me one thing what is the role of Google Pay enable,  there is no Google Pay Payment option.

Comment: Try to change `enableGooglePay: false` to `enableGooglePay: true` in your code

Comment: It is already true.

Comment: `var data = await braintreePayment.showDropIn(
    nonce: clientNonce, amount: "5.0", enableGooglePay: false);` it is false. Try to change it to true. If you changed it I do not know

Comment: Yes, I changed it but not updated here.